# Setting a pattern for a cell-background in Indesign using cell styles

Tags: adobe-indesign, tables, cell

I would like to set a patterned background (ex: hashed, spotted- effects that are easily done in Word) to some cells in a table in InDesign CS6. Even a gradient would do the trick, but I see the gradient is set to scale the whole table, not the cell alone. I need a solution that can be set into cell styles, not done manually. Also, the width and height of each cell may vary so using a background image is not a good solution. What can you suggest?

Comment: Hi user2069532, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Could you add an example visual of what you tried and what you're trying to achieve? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the diagonal line options.... `Table > Cell Options > Diagonal Lines`

[image]

While a bit limited, it would offer some variations, especially if you use color in conjunction with line directions.

Comment: Thanks, good idea. I really had in mind authentic stripes that can be edited how wide etc but this is definitely better than nothing. I appreciate the response.